# Bigquery SQL - Exclude rows/data for current Financial Year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query in which I want to add a WHERE clause to exclude data for current Financial Year (without hardcoding it)
Note: FinancialYear 1st July to 30 June

```
SELECT * from TABLE A
WHERE FinancialYear != Current_Financial_Year
```

Based on a date column I have extracted Financial Year as below but not sure how to check if its current financial year and then exclude it using the WHERE clause above

```
extract(year from date_add(CalendarDate, interval 6 month)) as FinancialYear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare to the current financial year by using similar logic on `current_date`:

```
where extract(year from date_add(CalendarDate, interval 6 month)) <>
      extract(year from date_add(Current_Date, interval 6 month))
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use the following query

```
select * from Table_A where FinancialYear NOT LIKE '%2021%'
```

All you need to change is the year and you will get the respective data :)
Regards :)

Comment: That would work but I want to avoid hardcoding current year.

Comment: Well, you still have one option which is 

set @yourVariableName:=yourValue;
select * from yourTableName where yourColumnName=@yourVariableName;

Do try this :)

Comment: There is nothing best about this approach.  Using string operations for date comparisons is usually a very, very bad idea -- even if the database lets you do it (BigQuery would probably generate a type-based syntax error in this case).